# Does EmEditor support conditionals and loops in a macro?

Tags: macros, emeditor

I am trying to create a macro that examines each line in a file and then performs different actions depending on some condition, for example:
`if condition A is true then ... else if condition B is true then ...`
and then repeats for the next line, until reaching the end of the file (EOF).

I haven't found any references for that in the manual or the Macro Reference, so I am working around it by creating a separate macro for each single condition, including a search string. I then run the macros sequentially using the **Run with Temporary Options...** menu and setting the **Repeat Count** to some arbitrary high number greater than the number of lines in the file, as well as setting the **Stop if Search Fails** option.

Not very elegant and a bit error-prone but it gets the job done. I suppose a plugin would be a better way to do this but that involves some additional programming complexity, which I am trying to avoid. Using *64-bit Pro v21.5.2*.

Comment: You can certainly use conditionals and loops in a macro because you can use JavaScript. Please learn JavaScript. If you need an example, please write a more specific question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I somehow assumed that the JavaScript/VBScript engines inside EmEditor were limited to the objects and methods as listed in the Macro Reference. Guess I should have just tried it first before asking silly questions.

Comment: See an example here: https://www.emeditor.com/forums/topic/macro-to-replace-string-on-a-specific-condition/